# iPhoneでナビゲーションの横スクロールを実現したい

Tags: ios, css

cssでナビゲーションの横スクロールを実装しようとしているんですが、うまくいきません。
環境はiPhone5c、iOS 10.3.3、Safari 602.1です。
下記のようにコードを書いているんですが、iPhoneでは全くスクロールできません。
PCやXperiaでは問題なくスクロールできています。
ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>nav1</li>
    <li>nav2</li>
    <li>nav3</li>
    <li>nav4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

.navigation {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

100vwという指定のため横スクロールしていないと思います。
vwという単位は、ビューポートの幅に対する割合のため100vwは、横幅ピッタリ１００％ということになります。
その為、少なくともiOSでは横スクロールは発生しません。（iOS11のSafariで確認）
vwを1000とかの値にすると、画面サイズよりもコンテンツサイズが大きくなるためiOSでも横スクロールが発生します。

Comment: やってみましたが、残念ながら横スクロールできませんでした。

Comment: うーん。ちょっと私が思っている状況と違うようですね。

Answer (score 1):

スニペットで表示しやすい様に加工しています。
 1. .navigationの幅を200pxにしました。
 2. li はおそらく横ならびだと思いますので、flexboxで並べました。   
 3. flex-wrapの初期値はnowrapなので、liは折り返しません。
 4. a もwhite-space: nowrapで改行なしにしました。
 5. ul の幅を明示的に .navigation よりも大きい300pxにしました。

```css
.navigation {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation ul {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 width: 300px;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.navigation li {
 flex-grow: 1;
 background-image: linear-gradient(30deg,#999,#e99);
}
.navigation a {
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>nav1</li>
    <li>nav2</li>
    <li>nav3</li>
    <li>nav4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ul の幅が .navigation よりも大きいか？がスクロールするかどうかのポイントだと思います。
li の数が足りないとか？